# WCF with non WCF Client

Tags: wcf, asmx

When consuming my WCF service from client, I get the following error message. Problem is when I am able to run the code easily from a windows client or a console app. Just not from my web application.

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
  Message="Client found response content type of 
  'multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml";start="<http://tempuri.org/0>";boundary="uuid:28551dc8-55af-4ec9-a9dc-169075c7f50a+id=6";start-info="text/xml"', but expected 'text/xml'. 
  The request failed with the error message: --  
  --uuid:28551dc8-55af-4ec9-a9dc-169075c7f50a+id=6 Content-ID: <http://tempuri.org/0> Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit Content-Type: application/xop+xml;charset=utf-8;type="text/xml"  
  <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><s:Fault><faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher">a:InternalServiceFault</faultcode><faultstring xml:lang="en-US">PrintOut3: Conversion failed</faultstring><detail><ExceptionDetail xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.ServiceModel" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><HelpLink i:nil="true"/><InnerException i:nil="true"/>
```

This is my WCF Service binding configuration

```
<basicHttpBinding>
  <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IMakePDFService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
    allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
    hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
    maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" 
    maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Mtom" 
    textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" 
      maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" 
      maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
    <security mode="None">
      <transport clientCredentialType="None" 
        proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
      <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
    </security>
  </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

Answer (score 1):

From the message, it appears that your WCF service is correctly returning a SOAP message, while your client might be expecting a raw POX (Plain Old XML) message back.

What kind of client is this? Are they expecting to just make a REST-style call to a URL and get back a payload of XML??

If so, you'll need to change your WCF service to use the `WebHttpBinding` instead of the basicHttpBinding (or expose a second endpoint with the `webHttpBinding` for that client).

Comment: Wish there was a way to mark this as an answer, i modified my web.config to weHttpBinding and it worked, however i had to also use this settings found on these pages <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798069/wcf-error-manual-addressing-is-enabled-on-this-factory-so-all-messages-sent-m> use the second best answer here and <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21204638/wcf-error-on-execute-manual-addressing-is-enabled-on-this-factory-so-all-messa>

Answer (score 1):

It seems the service returns MTOM encoded response which the client does not expect. The service configuration does not indicate that MTOM is used so maybe it is not wired correctly to the service. Check what the service actually returns using Fiddler or WCF Logging.

Comment: The configuration above was generated when the proxy was added using the svcutil tool.

Comment: first verify with fiddler that this is what the server returns. If it returns MTOM then publish the full web.config here.